# How can put the beginning of my array at the center of the screen?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, styling

So, I created a basic map function that show our array on the screen:

```
let numbers = new Array(41);

  for (let i = 0, num = 0; i < numbers.length; i++, num += 5) {
    numbers[i] = num;
  }

{numbers.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <Animated.View 
                key={index} 
                style={[
                  { transform: [{ translateY }] },
                ]}
              >
                <Text style={styles.text} onPress={SampleFunction.bind(item)}>{item}</Text>
              </Animated.View> 
            );
          })}
```

But this array actually starts in the beginning of the screen. I want my first element of this array to start on the center, so how can I do that?

Comment: Not sure about react native, But in css you will have your Text under a div element and div element will have style saying text-align:"center"

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout). It's responsive and powerful.

A simple example is

```js
<div className="grid">
    <element>You're code here </element>
</div>
```

CSS could be something like:

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  justify-items: center;
}
```

Helpful article:
[CSS Grid: Justification and Alignment](https://alligator.io/css/align-justify/)